# Code crashes when reading numbers into an array... C language

Tags: c, arrays, crash

Hey my code crashed when I start to input data into the array. The program is supposed to read numbers into an array and then insert a new number into the array and at the ends it arranges everything in an ascending order. I am not sure what is wrong with it. anyone got suggestions?

Here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

int main() // Main
{

printf ("COP2220 - Project 5 - Manuel Ubau\n\n"); //Program Starts and Explains

printf ("This program inserts a number into an array in order of magnitude\n\n");

//Local Declarations
int i,j;
int n; //size of array
int x;
int arr[MAX]; //the arrays maximun 100 numbers
int pos;


printf("Please enter the size of the array: "); //Asks for size of array

scanf("%d",&n); //Reads size of array

   for(i=0;i<n;i++) // Reads values of the array
   {
    printf("Enter number for element #%d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
   }

printf("\nThe Original Array is:");  //Prints original Array for reference

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      printf("\t%d",arr[i]);
    }


printf("\n\nEnter the value you want to insert into the arary: "); //Asks for X
scanf("%d",&x); //Reads number

     for(i=0;i<n;i++) // Determines position of the new number
     if(x<arr[i])
     {
       pos =i;
       break;
     }

     for(i=n;i>=pos;i--) //Displaces the array 1 space to the left so new number 
     arr[i]= arr[i-1];
     arr[pos]=x;       //Inserts the number into "pos" defined before

     for(i=0;i<=n;i++) // Arranges array
     {
      for(j=i;j<=n;j++)
         {
           if(arr[i] > arr[j])
             {
              int temp=arr[i];
              arr[i]=arr[j];
              arr[j]=temp;
             }
         }
      }

 printf("\nThe final array is:"); //Prints New array
   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
   {
      printf("\t%d",arr[i]);
   }

printf("\n\nThanks!\n");
return 0; //Program Ends
}
```

Thanks in advance. Oh btw the program doesnt crash in any particular input number. It seems more like a random crash.

Edit: The crash happens when I input random numbers that I type. but if I do it in order, it doesnt crash. For example if I do an array of size 10 and its values is 1 2 3...10 it works perfectly but as soon as I use random numbers like 100 456 54... etc some times it crashes and some times it works. I havent determined a right sequence to make it crash. and there is no output, the program closes automatically and doesnt let me see if it printed something else or not

Comment: Does it give you an error message?

Comment: And can you format your code so it's more readable (particularly indentation)?

Comment: no error... it just closes the loop and ends the program. I'll try to format it. It's my first time posting here sorry...

Comment: At what point does it stop? Can you point out which line? What input are you using when it stops? Does it give any output at all?

Comment: it stops when I start inputting the numbers that go into the original array. the for loop that scans the numbers into the array

Comment: What input are you using when it stops? Does it give any output at all? Can you run it, then paste the full output here? That could really help.

Comment: @user3043425 see my response below

Comment: the crash happens when I input random numbers that I type. but if I do it in order, it doesnt crash. For example if I do an array of size 10 and its values is 1 2 3...10 it works perfectly but as soon as I use random numbers like 100 456 54... etc some times it crashes and some times it works. I havent determined a right sequence to make it crash. and there is no output, the program closes automatically and doesnt let me see if it printed something else or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crashes when you set a value bigger than any other value when you ask for a value to be inserted because `pos` is not initialised and it contains a random value (infact in that case `x<arr[i]` is never satisfied).
You just need to initialise the pos properly (position n which is the next available one) before proceding

```
pos = n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++) { // Determines position of the new number
   if(x<arr[i])
   {
     pos =i;
     break;
   }
}
```

Note that you should also check that the user writes less than 10000 to the question related to the vector size (max 99 because you ask to add a number after) as size for the vector or you will have a buffer overflow there

Another error is in the loop. Let say that pos=0 is the correct pos.

```
for(i=n;i>=pos;i--) //Displaces the array 1 space to the left so new number 
   arr[i]= arr[i-1]; //pos (Copy pos-1)
```

In case in which pos is equal to 0 you try to copy arr[0]=arr[-1] that causes a crash. you need to do the loop as follows:

```
for(i=n;i>pos;i--) //Displaces the array 1 space to the left so new number 
   arr[i]= arr[i-1]; //pos (Copy pos-1)
```

So that the last copy is safe (arr[1]=arr[0]).

Comment: I made the change that you indicated but it still crashes... the crash happens when I input random numbers that I type. but if I do it in order, it doesnt crash. For example if I do an array of size 10 and its values is 1 2 3...10 it works perfectly but as soon as I use random numbers like 100 456 54... etc some times it crashes and some times it works. I havent determined a right sequence to make it crash.

Comment: @user3043425 That fix works when you set 1to10 and then you add 12 for example, it was crashing also in that case, I tried than with any sequence but I couldn't reproduce errors in other condition. I will have a look to the algorithm now

Comment: @user3043425 no others error that can lead to a crash. all other variables seems to be allocated and used correctly.

Comment: I found the numbers that can make it crash. The array size is 25. And the input is 43 23 12 65 43 67 and then crashes at element #7

Comment: @user3043425 is this the final fix?